# Как подключиться к нужному репозиторию github?

Tags: git, github

Есть репозиторий на гитхаб, я скачал файлы методом кнопки download вместо того что бы клонировать. И за этого файлы никак не связанны с тем репозиторием. Как сделать что бы файлы на моем пк подключились к тому репозиторию? ( Изменение сделал в локальных файлах, поэтому клонировать тот с гитхаба не вариант )

Comment: Сами же написали - "клонировать", только в новую папку, а потом в клоне заменить на ваши измененные, закомитить и запушить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это делается командой `git remote add`, но делать её можно только на существующем репозитории, так что вам понадобится ещё и `git init`. Потом вам понадобится получить из репозитория коммиты командой `git fetch` и сделать `git reset` чтобы вносить свои изменения не с нуля, а начиная с головы репозитория.

```
git init
git remote add origin url_репозитория
git fetch origin
git reset --mixed origin/master
git add измененные файлы
git commit -m "комментарий к коммиту"
git push -u origin master
```

URL репозитория можно получить нажав на ту самую кнопку Clone в интерфейсе github.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, зачем требуется
git fetch origin
и 
git reset --mixed origin/master

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa без этих команд у вас будет пустая локальная копия, из которой не получится ничего запушить (будет конфликт)

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Открой терминал, затем зайди в папку, где у тебя лежит скачанный файл. Теперь пропиши эти команды по порядку:

```
git init
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/твой_аккаунт/имя_репозитория.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: добавление README.md тут излишне: автор уже сделал локальное изменение, кроме того, этот файл уже мог быть в репозитории

Comment: @Mikhail Ionkin Совершенно верно, ты прав. :)